# USING Regular Expressions to Find IP Address from Email Header

Tags: python, regex, email

I have a question that i need to grab IP address from the following part of Email Header.

```
Received: from smtprelay.b.mail.com (smtprelay0225.b.mail.com. [11.11.11.11])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g7si12282480pat.225.2014.07.26.06.53.24
    for <a@gmail.com>;
```

I need the output only 11.11.11.11 using regular Expression in python.

An Help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\[)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?=\])
```

Try this.Use `re.findall`.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\[)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?=\])')
test_str = u"Received: from smtprelay.b.mail.com (smtprelay0225.b.mail.com. [11.11.11.11])\n by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g7si12282480pat.225.2014.07.26.06.53.24\n for <a@gmail.com>;"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/10

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to fetch the data which was present inside `[]` brackets.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Received: from smtprelay.b.mail.com (smtprelay0225.b.mail.com. [11.11.11.11])
...     by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g7si12282480pat.225.2014.07.26.06.53.24
...     for <a@gmail.com>;"""
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\])', s).group()
'11.11.11.11'
```

OR

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<![.\d])\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\b(?![.\d])', s)
['11.11.11.11']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex

```
(?<=\[)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?=\])
```

to extract the ip

see how the regex works: http://regex101.com/r/lI0rU3/1

```
x="""Received: from smtprelay.b.mail.com (smtprelay0225.b.mail.com. [11.11.11.11])
...     by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g7si12282480pat.225.2014.07.26.06.53.24
...     for <a@gmail.com>;"""
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\[)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?=\])', x)
['11.11.11.11']
```

Comment: @Avinash Glad to hear it worked !!!. Do accpet any of the answers which you like so that it could be usefull for some other thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> a="""from smtprelay.b.mail.com (smtprelay0225.b.mail.com. [11.11.11.11])
...     by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g7si12282480pat.225.2014.07.26.06.53.24
...     for <a@gmail.com>;"""
>>> re.findall(r'\[(.*)\]',a)
['11.11.11.11']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f=open("file")
>>> for line in f:
...   if "Received" in line:
...     print line.split("]")[0].split("[")[-1]
...
11.11.11.11
```